# React add default value to uncontrolled MUI textfield

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using React 17 and Mui 5. I have lag issue on my form page because all my textfields are controlled and if I have a long form and I type very very fast on my keyboard the `onChange` event will be triggered a lot and it will reload the render each time because I have `this.setState()` inside my `handleChange`.

So I got an idea, it's to set all my textfields uncontrolled by removing the props `value` and add `debounce` to my `handleChange` function. It works but I got a problem when I'm on my edit form. I have to take the current value from json response and set this value inside my textfield but I don't have the props `value` anymore. So I see I can use the props `defaultValue`. But the problem with this props it's that it will be set just once. So at the first render I'll get empty value and at the second render (after json response) I'll get the value but the `defaultValue` is always empty because the second render is ignored.

Then the only way I found to make it works it's to display the textfield only when the value is set :

```
              {this.state.my_var || hasGotJsonResponse && (
                <TextField
                  label="Label"
                  name="my_var"
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  defaultValue={this.state.my_var}
                />
              )}
```

It works but I don't really like to display the field only in certain condition. There is another way to solve my problem ? Or maybe there is a way to intialize `defaultProps` dynamically ?

Notice: I don't want to use `ref` at least there is an easy way to manage it on multiple input

**Edit**

I show you a simple snipet. Try to type very fast and you will notice the lag inside the textfield

```js
const inputFieldKeys = Array.from({
  length: 100
}).map((e, i) => "field_" + i.toString());

const App = (props) => {
  const [inputState, setInputState] = React.useState({});

  // this runs fine even without the `useCallback` optimization, at least for me
  const handleChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setInputState(oldState => ({ ...oldState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  }, [setInputState]);

  return ( <div>
      {inputFieldKeys.map(key=>(
      <MaterialUI.TextField name={key} key={key} value={inputState[key] || ""} onChange={handleChange}
      label={key}/>
    ))}
  </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: TextField, onChange & setState alone would not cause a lag. Can you share more so we have a better understanding of how your component functions? Particularly the `onChange` function and what all of it's internal function calls are.

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu all react app got this problem, check out my basic snippet and test it

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. The issue is with large state objects and how React rerenders components when state changes. `memo` will fix that. Posted an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is each of your inputs are re-rendering *when one of them changes*. When you make a change to `field_0` and the value is updated, since they are all sharing `state`, they will all re-render in the current setup.

I took your snippet and simply logged the renders. Try typing one letter in the first input, and watch all 99 other inputs re-render.

```js
const inputFieldKeys = Array.from({
  length: 100
}).map((e, i) => "field_" + i.toString());

const App = (props) => {
  const [inputState, setInputState] = React.useState({});

  // this runs fine even without the `useCallback` optimization, at least for me
  const handleChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setInputState(oldState => ({ ...oldState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  }, [setInputState]);
  
  const InputLogged = ({ name,  value, onChange, label }) => {
    console.log(`${name} input re-rendered`);
    return (<MaterialUI.TextField name={name} key={name} value={inputState[name] || ""} onChange={handleChange}
      label={name}/>);
  };
  
  return ( <div>
      {inputFieldKeys.map(key=>(
      <InputLogged name={key} key={key} value={inputState[key] || ""} onChange={handleChange}
      label={key} />
    ))}
  </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
```

The key is to tell each input component *when it should re-render* using [React memo](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/memo).

Here's your snippet with some small modifications. Now each Input only re-renders when it's own value changes.

```js
const inputFieldKeys = Array.from({
  length: 100
}).map((e, i) => "field_" + i.toString());

const Input = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log(`${props.field} input re-rendered`);
  return (
    <MaterialUI.TextField
      name={props.field}
      key={props.field}
      value={props.value} 
      onChange={props.handleChange}
      label={props.field}
    />
  );
});

const App = (props) => {
  const [inputState, setInputState] = React.useState(Object.fromEntries(inputFieldKeys.map((field) => [field, ""])));

  // this runs fine even without the `useCallback` optimization, at least for me
  const handleChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setInputState(oldState => ({ ...oldState,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    }));
  }, [setInputState]);

  return ( <div>
    {inputFieldKeys.map((field) => {
      const props = { field, handleChange, value: inputState[field] };
      return (
        <Input {...props} />
      )
    })}
  </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>
```

Take a look at [this sandbox demonstration](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react18-avoid-re-renders-usecontext-usememo-usecallback-memo-icvpz6) I created that helps better understand `memo` and how it pertains to component re-rendering when `state` changes.

Additionally, if you must use a `class component`, memoization is simply handled using [PureComponent](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/PureComponent). This implements `componentDidUpdate` under-the-hood which does a shallow comparison of props and only re-renders when they change.

Simply use:

`class Greeting extends PureComponent {}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok I see I have to create a custom textfield component and wrap mui textfield inside memo to avoid the re-rendering if it's not needed right ? I think React.memo is a good solution. Do you know if it's possible to do that in class component ? If it's possible can you show me how I can do that ? Because my project got some hook component and the other are class component :/

Comment: Yes, although I advise rewriting class components into functional components. You would use `class Greeting extends PureComponent {}`. PureComponent handles memoization based on props. Updated the answer.

Comment: It's weird I tried to create another textfield component but I all my inputs refresh again  my component is very simple : 
`import React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";

const AmazingInput = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log(props);
  return <TextField {...props} />;
});

export default AmazingInput;`
I did something wrong ?

Comment: `memo` works with spread props as well. What are your `props`? I revised my example snippet to show the spread props working in the same way as normal props.

Comment: It's ok I think the problem it's caused by other component in my form, I replaced all and it works, thank you very much !

Comment: For component we can use shouldComponentUpdate like this : 
`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    // Compare the current props and state with the next props and state
    if (nextProps.value === this.props.value) {
      return false; // Don't update the component
    }

    return true;
  }`